# How can I add a border to an individual DataGridView column?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to somehow show the user that a specific column in a `DataGridView` is editable.

I want to add a `Fixed3D` border to only that column, but could not find a way.

How can I change the border style for a specific column?

Or, if that is not possible, are there any other ways to indicate that a cell can be edited?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply draw a rectangle on that column, and you can move it or change its style programatically.

Comment: Thanks, seems to be a solution but is there any way to have the pen to show as fixed3d?